# Case insensitive search in search2.js

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I am using select2.js in my project for drop down functionality. By default behaviour this is case sensitive i.e tag and Tag will be consider different.

But as per my requirement i required result populate is case insensitive i.e. when writing tag or Tag both need to considered to be small like in capital. I have tried many solution for this but non of that seems to working. I need to deal this client side only.

Issue is like  this `"https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/select2/vk86jUMfJTk"`

```
$('#Taging').select2({
        tags : true,
        tokenSeparators : [ ',' ],
        createSearchChoice : function(term) {
            return {
                id : term,
                text : term,
                n : "new",
                s : ""

            };
        },

        ajax : {

        },

        // Take default tags from the input value
        initSelection : function(element, callback) {
            var data = [];


            $(splitVal(element.val(), ",")).each(function() {
                data.push({
                    id : this,
                    text : this
                });
            });

            callback(data);
        },

    });
```

sample Code

Answer (score 0):

I modified my code and that works

```
createSearchChoice : function(term,data) {
            if (term.trim().length > 0) {
                if ($(data).filter(function () {
                  return this.text.toLowerCase().localeCompare(term.toLowerCase()) === 0;
                }).length === 0) {
                    return {
                        id: term,
                        text: term,
                        n : "new",
                        s : "",
                        isNew: true // this is necessary to check if the item is newly added or not
                    };
                }
            }
        },
```